# Multiple code blocks locked by the same object

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c#-4.0

If I have something like this:

```
private readonly object objectLock = new object();

public void MethodA()
{
    lock(objectLock)
    {
      //do something
    }
}

public void MethodB()
{
    lock(objectLock)
    {
      //do something
    }
}
```

If I have 2 threads and both come in at the same time, 1st thread calls MethodA and second Method B. Whichever gets there first and locks objectLock, I assume the other thread sits there waiting until objectLock is no longer locked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, your explanation is right -- unless the lock is already taken (in which case both threads sit waiting, and an arbitrary one gets the lock as soon as it's unlocked).

(Slightly offtopic) I would advise not to lock the whole methods if they are doing something non-trivial. Try to keep the "locking" section of code as small and as fast as possible.

Answer (score 5):

That is correct.

However it is not the objectLock that is locked (nor the object) it is the code blocks that are locked.

Think of the object that is passed to the `lock` keyword as a key that does unlock multiple doors but only grants access to a single room at one time.

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely right! But be careful with locks. Locks will maybe make you're program thread-safe (means, no errors on concurrent accesses) but it takes much more effort making make your program taking real advantage from running on a multi-kernel system.

Answer (score 0):

yes you are right as Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit is called on same object objectLock behind the scene. remember its the code block that is synchronized not the objectLock.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct. If this isn't desirable, then consider that:

```
lock(objectLock)
{
  //do something
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
Monitor.Enter(objectLock);
try
{
  //do something
}
finally
{
  Monitor.Exit(objectLock);
}
```

You can replace this with:

```
if(Monitor.TryEnter(objectLock, 250))//Don't wait more than 250ms
{
  try
  {
    //do something
  }
  finally
  {
    Monitor.Exit(objectLock);
  }
}
else
{
  //fallback code
}
```

It's also worth looking at the overloads of `TryEnter()`, and the other synchronisation objects such as `ReaderWriterLockSlim`.